# Multiple full outer join (from data in same table)

Tags: sql, join, amazon-athena

I have some log data that looks like the following

**Logs**

```
+---------------------+---------+---------+------+
|        date         | api_key | version | data |
+---------------------+---------+---------+------+
| 2018-05-08 01:00:00 | AAA     | v1      | data |
| 2018-05-08 02:00:00 | AAA     | v2      | data |
| 2018-05-06 03:00:00 | AAA     | v2      | data |
| 2018-05-06 04:00:00 | BBB     | v1      | data |
+---------------------+---------+---------+------+
```

- `date` is the date the API call was made
- `api_key` is the API key used
- `version` is the version of the API used (we have two)

This data currently lives in a RDBMS, I need to move the data to Athena.

**Aggregation**

There is some legacy code which runs periodically to aggregate the logs. This aggregation data is then displayed on a dashboard. Essentially it turns the flat log data (above) into data aggregated by API key, giving counts of calls made based on version, and in different time windows (all time, within 1 day, 7 days, etc)

For example, the following aggregate table shows the raw data aggregated.

```
+---------+------+---------+---------+--------+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| api_key | hits | hits_v1 | hits_v2 | hits_1 | hits_1_v1 | hits_1_v2 | hits_7 | hits_7_v1 | hits_7_v2 |
+---------+------+---------+---------+--------+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| AAA     |    3 |       1 |       2 |      2 |         1 |         1 |      3 |         1 |         2 |
| BBB     |    1 |       1 |       0 |      0 |         0 |         0 |      1 |         1 |         0 |
+---------+------+---------+---------+--------+-----------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

These are what the columns mean:

- `hits` the number of all time calls by the given `api-key`
- `hits_v1` the number of all time calls by the given `api-key` for `v1`
- `hits_v2` the number of all time calls by the given `api-key` for `v2`
- `hits_1` the number of calls in the last day by the given `api-key`
- `hits_1_v1` the number of `v1` calls in the last day by the given `api-key`
- `hits_1_v2` the number of `v2` calls in the last day by the given `api-key`
- `hits_7` the number of calls in the last 7 days by the given `api-key`
- `hits_7_v1` the number of `v1` calls in the last 7 days by the given `api-key`
- `hits_7_v2` the number of `v2` calls in the last 7 days by the given `api-key`

**SQL**

Below is the SQL I use to create this aggregate table.

```
SELECT coalesce(hits_v1.api_key, hits_v2.api_key, hits_1_v1.api_key, hits_1_v2.api_key) api_key,
    coalesce(hits_v1.hits_v1,0) + coalesce(hits_v2.hits_v2,0) hits, 
    coalesce(hits_v1.hits_v1,0) hits_v1, 
    coalesce(hits_v2.hits_v2,0) hits_v2,

    coalesce(hits_1_v1.hits_1_v1,0) + coalesce(hits_1_v2.hits_1_v2,0) hits_1, 
    coalesce(hits_1_v1.hits_1_v1,0) hits_1_v1, 
    coalesce(hits_1_v2.hits_1_v2,0) hits_1_v2,

    coalesce(hits_7_v1.hits_7_v1,0) + coalesce(hits_7_v2.hits_7_v2,0) hits_7, 
    coalesce(hits_7_v1.hits_7_v1,0) hits_7_v1, 
    coalesce(hits_7_v2.hits_7_v2,0) hits_7_v2
FROM 
(
    (select api_key,count(*) as hits_v1 from logs where (version='v1' or version='') group by api_key) hits_v1
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (select api_key,count(*) as hits_v2 from logs where version='v2' group by api_key) hits_v2                                                                       on hits_v2.api_key   = hits_v1.api_key

    FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (select api_key,count(*) as hits_1_v1 from logs where (version='v1' or version='') and (date > localtimestamp - interval '1' day) group by api_key) hits_1_v1    on hits_1_v1.api_key = coalesce(hits_v1.api_key, hits_v2.api_key)
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (select api_key,count(*) as hits_1_v2 from logs where version='v2' and (date > localtimestamp - interval '1' day) group by api_key) hits_1_v2                    on hits_1_v2.api_key = coalesce(hits_v1.api_key, hits_v2.api_key, hits_1_v1.api_key)

    FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (select api_key,count(*) as hits_7_v1 from logs where (version='v1' or version='') and (date > localtimestamp - interval '7' day) group by api_key) hits_7_v1    on hits_7_v1.api_key = coalesce(hits_v1.api_key, hits_v2.api_key, hits_1_v1.api_key, hits_1_v2.api_key)
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (select api_key,count(*) as hits_7_v2 from logs where version='v2' and (date > localtimestamp - interval '7' day) group by api_key) hits_7_v2                    on hits_7_v2.api_key = coalesce(hits_v1.api_key, hits_v2.api_key, hits_1_v1.api_key, hits_1_v2.api_key, hits_7_v1.api_key)
)
order by api_key asc
```

As you can see, it's pretty repetitive, and verbose. Even worse, the more columns I need to add (14 days, 30 days, 60 days, etc) I need to add to the `on` clause each time to include the all previous joins.

This works, but I'm sure there must be a cleaner way of doing this. Can anyone help please?

PS. Yes I do need to keep this aggregation table - it might not be nice, but a whole bunch of other code relies on it being that way, so it can't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select api_key,
       sum(case when version = 'v1' or version = '' then 1 else 0 end) AS hits_v1,
       sum(case when version = 'v2' then 1 else 0 end) AS hits_v2,
       sum(case when (version = 'v1' or version = '') and (date > localtimestamp - interval '1' day) then 1 else 0 end) as hits_v1_1,
       . . .
from logs l
group by api_key;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon - that looks good. You've given 'hits_v1' and 'hits_v2' as an example which works well, however, I also need 'hits' which is the sum of both  'hits_v1' and 'hits_v2'. How would I include that in my query? Thanks again.

Comment: @swalesong . . . Just include all three conditions in the `when` clause.

Comment: doh.. Of course, that makes perfect sense. I also like @D-Shih suggestion as well. I'll accept this answer as I think the main thing was to use the conditional aggregation, but both were super helpful. Thanks so much to both of you - you've made my query so much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query instead of your subquery.

If you want to get `hits`

- `hits` the number of all time calls by the given `api-key`

You can choose `count(1)` to get all data.

```
SELECT api_key,
       count(1) hits,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (version='v1' or version='') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) hits_v1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (version = 'v2' or version='') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) hits_v2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (date > localtimestamp - interval '1' day) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) hits_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (date > localtimestamp - interval '1' day) and (version='v1' or version='') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) hits_1_v1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (date > localtimestamp - interval '1' day) and (version='v2' or version='') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) hits_1_v2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN (date > localtimestamp - interval '7' day) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) hits_7,
       SUM(CASE WHEN  (version='v1' or version='') and (date > localtimestamp - interval '7' day) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) hits_7_v1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN  (version='v2' or version='') and (date > localtimestamp - interval '7' day) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) hits_7_v2
FROM logs
group by api_key
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be990/5*